Converting two 2d arrays of different shapes into a 3d array
How to convert two 2d arrays of shapes (629, 5) and (629, 6) into a 3d array of shape (629, 5, 6)?
Input:
[[2, 5, 6, 7, 8],
 [3, 5, 6, 7, 8],
 [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]

[[2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]

Output:
[[[2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]], 
 [[3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]], 
 [[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]]


Convert how? Can you give a reproducible unambiguous example (inputs+output) for a smaller shape (e.g. (3,5) and (3,6): np.arange(3*5).reshape(3, 5) and np.arange(3*6).reshape(3, 6))

thank you for reminding me to add an example

Your example is not complete. You are just replicating the second array. What happened to the first array? Use differrnt numbers

That replication is exactly what I want.

If you just want to broadcast arr2 you could use broadcast_to:
arr1 = np.array([[2, 5, 6, 7, 8],
                 [3, 5, 6, 7, 8],
                 [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]])
arr2 = np.array([[2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
                 [3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
                 [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])

out = np.broadcast_to(arr2[:,None], (*arr1.shape, arr2.shape[1]))

or numpy.repeat:
out = np.repeat(arr2[:,None], arr1.shape[1], axis=1)

Output:
# shape: (3, 5, 6)
array([[[2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]],

       [[3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]],

       [[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]])


Thank you, I was not aware of broadcasting.

Or to golf it a bit, assuming numbers: np.ones_like(arr1[...,None])*arr2[:,None] ;)
